# How to select all text in a textbox and copy it to clipboard using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox with an 'Add to clipboard' button next to it. Whenever the copy to clipboard button is pressed, I want the contents of the clipboard to get copied to the clipboard, and work in a cross browser way across Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc. I can use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or plain [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the [jQuery clipboard plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy) might do the job well. You can use the selector notation with it too, ot the utility `$.copy`

**EDIT:**

[ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) is another choice and this does appear to [work well](http://bowser.macminicolo.net/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/) (tested in Firefox 3.5, IE 6 and Chrome)

Comment: The jQuery one seems not to have been updated to cope with the new security model in Flash 10 (following a load of annoying clipboard-corrupting attacks). You pretty much have to let the Flash interface take the click now before you can set clipboard; that's what ZeroClipboard does.