# Copy to clipboard using jquery for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select all text in a textbox and copy it to clipboard using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390953/how-to-select-all-text-in-a-textbox-and-copy-it-to-clipboard-using-javascript-jq)
>   [Copy text to the client’s clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

I need a javascript, jquery function for copy to clipboard functionality. I know following code but it works in IE only:

```
holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
```

I see some tutorials which are suggestion some swf files. I have used some of them like http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ but it is not working.

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: AFAIK there is no cross-browser solutions besides flash.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any cross-browser way to copy data to the clipboard via javascript (it's regarded as a security hole) - it can be done with the assistance of a small flash applet, but this of course isn't fully cross platform.

One of the cheats I've used before is to create a `prompt` with a default value in which makes it slightly easier for the user to copy-and-paste the information without having to highlight it in the page. But this doesn't really solve the problem. All you can do is make the copy-and-paste as little effort as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The mainstream way of doing this is via a SWF object. [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) is a neat project which deals with this.